# Forceful reset of Entity Framework Migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I had an issue where some of my migrations weren't quite working and I didn't seem to be able to fix it. Therefore I decided to start again. I did the following:

- Deleted the migration history table in the database
- Deleted all the EF tables
- Deleted the migrations folder from my project
- Uninstalled EF5 via NuGet.

I then re-installed EF5 and ran the following;

> Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations -Force

This creates my migration.cs file but doesn't touch the database. If I run some code that tries to use the context it complains that the tables don't exist. So I then created a migration:

> Add-Migration InitialCreate

The migration this creates however has **remembered** some state, ignoring the fact it needs to create tables and just lists:

```
 public partial class InitialCreate : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.NetC_EF_ShippingRate", "CurrencyName", c => c.String());
        AddColumn("dbo.NetC_EF_ShippingRate", "CreationDate", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.NetC_EF_ShippingRate", "CreationDate");
        DropColumn("dbo.NetC_EF_ShippingRate", "CurrencyName");
    }
}
```

How can I get it to **forget** the state fully and create all tables etc related to the context as if I was starting from scratch?

**EDIT** I should probably add if I simply try and run this manually created migration I just get errors:

> Cannot find the object "dbo.NetC_EF_ShippingRate" because it does not
>   exist or you do not have permissions.

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <!--<providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>-->
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FreightContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Persist Security Info=False;database=DS_Kentico;server=FS-01\DEVSQL2008R2;user id=****;password=****;Current Language=English;Connection Timeout=240;" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

**web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="CMSConnectionString" connectionString="Persist Security Info=False;database=DeltaShelving_Kentico;server=FS-01\DEVSQL2008R2;user id=generic_webuser;password=generic_webuser;Current Language=English;Connection Timeout=240;" />
    <add name="FreightContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Persist Security Info=False;database=DS_Kentico;server=FS-01\DEVSQL2008R2;user id=****;password=****;Current Language=English;Connection Timeout=240;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: As I understand it, neither of the two commands you used `Enable-Migrations` or `Add-Migration` actually push anything to the database. The command to do that is `Update-Database`.
However, the fact your migrations don't include any create table calls is a bit strange. Do the tables still exist in the database?

Comment: @Richard: I believe you're correct with your statement. No, I removed the tables from the database which is why I'm so confused.

Comment: @Richard: I think I've tracked down part of the problem. The verbose flag on a bad migration shows that it's pointing to the wrong database: Target database is: 'NetC.CustomModules.Freight.FreightContext' (DataSource: (localdb)\v11.0, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention). Unfortunately I can't find the string in any config files. Both my app.config and main web.config appear correct

Comment: ah ok. The database name its trying to find is derived based on convention. In the absence of any explicit connection string, EF will use the name of your custom DbContext as the db name. It also trying to look for a connections string with the same name first. So in your case it will be looking for a connection string called "FreightContext" and failing to find it

Comment: @Richard: Makes sense - but I've just posted my app.config for the project with the context, and my web.config for the context. Both look correct to me?

Comment: When you run your commands do you target a specific project with `-ProjectName` or is it reverting to the default project? Whichever way, does the project its targeting have the connection string in its app.config? I'm assuming yes, and that the app.config you listed is the one, but just making sure.

Comment: I've set the default project in the package manager dropdown, although running did this: PM> Update-Database -Verbose -ProjectName NetC.Delta.CustomModules
Using StartUp project 'Tests'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'FreightContext' (DataSource: (localdb)\v11.0, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention).
No pending code-based migra

Comment: @Richard: I think that got it. Wrong startup project = missing app.config so it's tried to update the wrong database. Setting the correct project seems to fix it. Can you add your suggestion as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework will be looking for a valid connection string in the app.config of the target project. In this case it can't find it.

The target project for EF Migrations is specified either by the `-ProjectName` option on the `Add-Migration` command, or it reverts to the default project as defined in the Package Manager Console.

Try setting the project name explicitly to the project that contains your DbContext.

Comment: In this case despite the fact I specified the default project and even tried the -ProjectName it was still using the Startup project to find the connection string. Changing this to an appropriate project (not tests) fixed my issue. Thanks